# Get image file name from Div and copy into text field on button hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, function, button

In a div with id #prlogo i have am image. I need to copy the filename or location of the image on the server to a text filed with id #input_2_16, when i hover over a button with id #button.

Sounds simple but i've been pulling my hair out trying to do this...

Div html:

```
<div id="prlogo" class="prlogo"><img class="logoplace" src="../preview/logo-place.png"/>
        </div>
```

Miro

Comment: Can you give us the html of the div and the text field?

Comment: Is the image a child of the div, or background of the div?

Comment: Just added the html of the div. not a background image... a child.

Comment: We can't be sure we're giving you a correct answer until you post ALL of the involved html. If you want even more help, you could post all the code that you tried which didn't work and people will probably pinpoint exactly where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more context and using jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { //this anonymous function will run when the page is ready
    $("#button").hover(function() {
      //mouse enter
      var imgSrc = $("#prlogo img").attr("src"); 
      //assumes there is an <img /> tag as a child of the #prlogo div
      $("#input_2_16").val(imgSrc);
    },function() {
      //mouse leave
    });
});
</script>
```

If you don't want to do anything on mouse leave you could instead do

```
$("#button").mouseenter(function() {
  //mouse enter
  var imgSrc = $("#prlogo img").attr("src"); 
  //assumes there is an <img /> tag as a child of the #prlogo div
  $("#input_2_16").val(imgSrc);
});
```

Comment: thats great, thank you... only thing though, the button has an input id of button, not div id. any ideas?

Comment: huh? This mouse enter / hover event will fire when you move your mouse over ANY element with `id="button"`

Comment: it dosent seem to work... it only works when i put a class instead of an id

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with the same id? Because that's not allowed. That's the only thing I can think of that would make the code not work.

Comment: no, thats the only element with that id... i dont know either... this is why i have been pulling my hair...

Comment: reading my earlier comment, by any element, i meant any **type** of element. Use classes if you need to identify multiple elements, use IDs as unique identifiers for single elements.

Comment: Well i cant use the class as its used in more than one place and updates a lot of filds... but combining the id with the class worked... not sure why this is

Answer (score 0):

If I read this correctly, it would be something like this:

```
$( function () {
    $( '#button' ).mouseover( function () {
        var src = $( '#prlogo img' ).attr( 'src' );
        $( '#input_2_16' ).val( src );
    } );
} );
​
```

Comment: thats great, thank you... only thing though, the button has an input id of button, not div id. any ideas?

Comment: Oh, so it's an input button?  Then you would change the selector to `$( 'input[type=button]' )`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to transverse more than one level down the DOM, use .find in place of .children.

```
$('#button').on('hover', function(){
        $('#input_2_16').val($('#prlogo').children('img').attr('src'));
});
```